# How to conditionally filter out children in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I currently have something similar to the following XML:

```
<div class="newsFeed">
   <div class="newsItem"><news position="3"/></div>
   <categoryFilter dayFilter="4">
       <div class="newsItem"><news position="2"/></div>
   </categoryFilter>
</div>
```

I need to copy the XML, and output the nth news item on the  node.  Futhermore, I need to be able to filter that news.  For this example, lets construct my news as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="news">
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to 30">
        <item>
          <day><xsl:value-of select=". mod 4" /></day>
          <content>Content: <xsl:value-of select="." /></content>
        </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

I actually use `document()` and use the for-each to sort it, but I'm trying to keep it succinct.  This would mean that my output XML would be something like the following:

```
<div class="newsFeed">
    <div class="newsItem">Content: 3</div>  
    <div class="newsItem">Content: 8</div>  
 </div>
```

The reason the second one is `8` is because the categoryFilter filters out every `<item>` where the day isn't `4` (which happens to be the 4th, 8th, 12th, and so on), and then we select the second one.

The XSLT to produce the above is as follows:

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="news">
   <xsl:param name="items" select="$news" />
   <xsl:variable name="position" select="@position" />
   <xsl:copy-of select="$items/item[position()=$position]/content" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="categoryFilter">
   <xsl:param name="items" select="$news" />
   <xsl:variable name="day" select="@dayFilter" />
   <xsl:variable name="filteredItems">
      <xsl:for-each select="$items/item[day=$day]">
         <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$filteredItems">
   </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem lies with the `<for-each>`.  It seems silly that I have to use a for-each to filter out the `<item>` nodes, but I can't find a better way.  Simply doing a `<xsl:variable select="$items/item[day=$day]">` changes the structure, and makes it so that the `<xsl:template match="news">` doesn't work.

Is there a way to filter out child nodes without using a for-each?  I am using `<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0">`

Comment: I couldn't figure out what your question is. What is your input, and what is the output you're trying to get?-- You should also clarify if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k does the bolded statement explain better?

Comment: No. You are explaining what you're doing (which makes very little to no sense to me). Instead, you should explain what you have to start with (your XML input) and what do you want to end up with (your output) - and why. To *"do $filteredItems/item[position() = 1]*" is not a goal; it's a means to achieve a goal (probably not very effective means at that).

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have a bunch of templates that have a parameter `items`, and call `$items/item[position() = 1]`. I need the parameter to be structured the same way, so the templates still work even if I have filtered some of their children out.  Does that clear up my goal?

Comment: If you are really interested, my output is a news feed.  I use `document()` to read off all of the news items, and pass those items as a parameter as I transform the original document.  As I go down, certain nodes may filter out certain news items (say, I want to print news only from the year X).

Comment: Please supply one or more test cases. A test case is a sample input document and the matching expected output document.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin I added a (hopefully) comprehensive test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this...

```
<xsl:variable name="filteredItems">
   <xsl:for-each select="$items/item[day=$day]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

... you could use a sequence. This will select the actual items, as opposed to create copies of them

```
<xsl:variable name="filteredItems">
   <xsl:sequence select="$items/item[day=$day]" />
</xsl:variable>
```

This was, doing `$filteredItems/item` will still work.

Alternatively, you could take the opposite approach, and do away with the need to specify `/item` in all the expressions.

First, define your `news` variable like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="news" as="element()*">
```

This means you can write the expression that uses it like so:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$news[position()=$position]/content" />
```

And similarly for `filteredItems`....

```
<xsl:variable name="filteredItems" select="$items[day=$day]" />
```

Comment: Thank you.  Just so I understand what is going on here, by default, putting a for-each inside a variable defines the variable as a sequence?  Where can I find the differences on a sequence and an `element()*`?

Comment: Whether you use `xsl:for-each` or a `xsl:sequence` inside a variable, the variable itself will create a new document node, and the `item` nodes will be children of that. By using `as="element()*"` you tell it not to use a document node, but just return the elements themselves. There are some good Q&A's on sequences at http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/rev2/sequences.html